# Content Management having processing/aggregation config files Sitecore 8.1

Tags: xdb, content-management

I have a question regarding Content Management configuration settings. I have setup our CM environment as per [Sitecore's instructions](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_management_server). I. In the excel sheet provided, I have filter out ‘Enable’ under Content Management (CM) column, you’ll see below files are enabled.

[image]

However according to this [document](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/server_considerations/server_configuration_features?roles=marketer), these configuration files are processing/aggregation features.

With that said, my question is given that those files are enabled in our CM environment would that mean our CM is serving as CM + processing/aggregation?
Is there any anything I need to watch on disabling these configs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your current infrastructure setup? I mean are using separate CD and Cm, job server, processing server etc

Comment: Hi Hishaam - we are using CM(with reporting) and CD and Processing/Aggregation server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aggregation pipelines should be disabled on CM since you have a processing server. Because the role of the processing server is just to perform aggregation of analytics data to the Reporting database.

If you have agents/jobs running on CM, then you need to have the `Sitecore.Processing.config` enabled on CM.

The `Sitecore.Processing.config` is not for Analytics but Sitecore Tasks. It is the task that you configure on the Sitecore CMS.

You may also read the following [article](https://robearlam.com/blog/configuring-a-shared-reporting-processing-instance-in-sitecore-8-0) by Rob Earlam since you will see that there are conflicting configuration.

Comment: Hi Hishaam - thanks for your reply now it's clear. I've started working on identifying configurations that are part of aggregations and other processing related tasks to remove them in our CM environment. It helped as well looking at the comments in the header of each configuration.